# Is it possible to send through the SOAP API to an DataExtension using a Publication List?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, send-email, publicationlist

We are sending to a Data Extension using the SOAP API.
Is it possible to use an Publication List in this Call? So if an User click the Standard Unsubscribe Link in the Email that he is only unsubscribed from this Publication List and not the AllSubscriber List?
If yes how i write the Code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <h:fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com" xmlns:h="http://exacttarget.com">ACCESS_TOKEN
        </h:fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:CreateRequest>
            <ns1:Options></ns1:Options>
            <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:EmailSendDefinition">
                <ns1:CustomerKey>SEND_DEFINITION_KEY</ns1:CustomerKey>
                <ns1:Name>SEND_DEFINITION_KEY</ns1:Name>
                <ns1:Description>DESCRIPTION</ns1:Description>
                <ns1:SendClassification>
                    <ns1:CustomerKey>Default Commercial</ns1:CustomerKey>
                </ns1:SendClassification>
                <ns1:SenderProfile>
                    <ns1:CustomerKey>default</ns1:CustomerKey>
                </ns1:SenderProfile>
                <ns1:DeliveryProfile>
                    <ns1:CustomerKey>Default</ns1:CustomerKey>
                </ns1:DeliveryProfile>
                <ns1:SendDefinitionList>
                    <ns1:CustomerKey>DATAEXTENSION_DER_GRUPPE_1</ns1:CustomerKey>
                    <ns1:DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</ns1:DataSourceTypeID>
                </ns1:SendDefinitionList>
                <ns1:Email>
                    <ns1:ID>EMAIL_ID</ns1:ID>
                </ns1:Email>
            </ns1:Objects>
        </ns1:CreateRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The publication list would need to be specified in the SendDefintionList property List, the example below 111111 represents the ID of the publication list.

```
<ns1:SendDefinitionList>
    <ns1:List>
        <ns1:ID>111111</ns1:ID>
    </ns1:List>
    <ns1:CustomerKey>DATAEXTENSION_DER_GRUPPE_1</ns1:CustomerKey>
    <ns1:DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</ns1:DataSourceTypeID>
</ns1:SendDefinitionList>
```